# Calling `super` in Objective-C category

Tags: objective-c, categories, superclass, super

I have a class called `Animal` which is a subclass of `BaseEntity`. I have a protocol called `CoreDataConversions` which both `Animal` and `BaseEntity` have categories that conform to. In the protocol I have a method defined:

`- (instancetype)initWithManagedObject:(NSManagedObject *)managedObject dataManager:(id<DataManager>)dataManager`

`BaseEntity` category implements this fine. Then, because `Animal` is a subclass of `BaseEntity` I make a call to `[super initWithManagedObject:managedObject dataManager:dataManager];` in the animal category.

I get a crash with the message:

> `[Animal setDataManager:]` unrecognized selector sent to instance...

I set a break point at the call to super and logged out the following:

```
po [self class] // Prints Animal

po [self superclass] // Prints BaseEntity

po [super class] // Prints Animal

po [super superclass] // Prints BaseEntity
```

So: Why is the `Animal` category's `super` making calls to `Animal` even though calls to `superclass` clearly refer to `BaseEntity`?

EDIT:

Here's the code that causes the crash:

```
- (id)insertEntityForClass:(Class)class
{
    if (![class conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CoreDataConversions)]) {
        return nil;
    }

    // A class method defined in CoreDataConversions
    NSString *entityName = [class coreDataEntityName];

    // Insert core data entity
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.currentMainContext];

    // Init with the managed object
    id entity = [[class alloc] initWithManagedObject:managedObject dataManager:self];

    return entity;
}
```

I have a test that simply calls `Animal *animal = [dataManager insertEntityForClass:[Animal class]];` and then asserts the existence of `animal`.

`Animal` implements the method like so:

```
- (instancetype)initWithManagedObject:(NSManagedObject *)managedObject dataManager:(id<RHDataManager>)dataManager
{    
    self = [super initWithManagedObject:managedObject dataManager:dataManager];
    if (self) {
        // TODO
    }
    return self;
}
```

And `BaseEntity` implements the method like so:

```
- (instancetype)initWithManagedObject:(id)managedObject dataManager:(id<RHDataManager>)dataManager
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.dataManager = dataManager;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code around the crash, indicating the class it's in.  Just to make the question clearer.

Comment: @danh just added the code around the crash

Comment: I might be being dense, but I don't see a call to `setDataManager` in the posted code

Comment: It occurs in the `BaseEntity` implementation of `initWithManagedObject: dataManager:` (last code snippet)

Comment: I see.  Sorry.  I don't think it has anything to do with the category.

Comment: Yes you're right it turns out it's to do with property declarations.

Comment: Note that is very easy with this approach to drift into undefined behavior. A category cannot override a superclass's methods, and if two categories implement the same method, it is undefined which one is called. You're not quite doing that, so this is at the very edge of defined behavior. The point of categories is to add independent functionality, not participate in inheritance. There are many ways for it to go subtly (and surprisingly) wrong when categories are involved in overrides the way you're doing it here.

Comment: Note that the part about `[self class]` returning the same thing as `[super class]` and `[self superclass]` returning the same thing as `[super superclass]` is normal and is the same in all OO languages (Java, etc.). `super` does not call a method on a different object -- it calls a method on `self`. It's just that which implementation of that method is called could be different.

Comment: `[self foo]` determines which implementation of `foo` to call based on the runtime class of `self`, whereas `[super foo]` determines which implementation of `foo` to call based on the superclass of the class the that source code is in. In this case, for both methods `-class` and `-superclass`, none of your classes have overridden these methods, and these methods are usually never overridden. So there is only one implementation of these methods -- the one inherited from the `NSObject` class. So there is no difference between calling it with `self` or `super`.

Comment: The same method implementation is called. And they are called on the same object -- `self`. Therefore, the result must be the same.

Comment: If a class B inherits from class A surely `[super class]` called from class B should return class A?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is actually to do with property declarations. I had `readonly` properties i.e. `@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) id<DataManager> dataManager;` defined in the the original class.

The in the category I had redefined the property like so:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) id<DataManager> dataManager;`

The crash was caused because there was no setter set in `Animal` for the `dataManager` because it was still reading it as `readonly`.